# In php cli, how to redirect?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have the following code stored in a file called index.php.

```
<?php
file_put_contents(date('Y-m-d-H-i-s', time()) . '.txt', '123');
sleep(1);
header("Location: ./index.php", true, 301);
?>
```

In a browser, it creates a file every second, but when I run it in php CLI (php -f index.php) it just creates one file.

How can I use redirect in the php CLI?

Comment: You don't need `time()` in your `date()` call, either. It defaults to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command line interface (CLI) cannot redirect because it is not a browser. What you need is a loop. Try looking up a 'for loop' or a 'while loop'. A 'for loop' repeats code a number of times and a 'while loop' repeats code until a condition is met.

For example the following code will loop 10 times:

```
for ( $counter = 0; $counter < 10; $counter++) {
    file_put_contents(date('Y-m-d-H-i-s', time()) . '.txt', '123');
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: you should do that for a web version as well, far more efficient.

Comment: this is not my purpose,i want to redirect to a.php to send a email, do diffrent things, not the same things.

Comment: makes no sense to redirect (Location is part of the http protocol) to another file using the php cli. you need to more fully explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i want to do two things, one thing is loop echo 'XXX' many times, it take almost 30s,  another thing is send a email to notify. when this two things in one process, it will be timeout, I want to separate them in two processes.

Comment: @user1514160 so use a loop like the example above. I think you should post a new question with a LOT more detail

Comment: OK, what's you meaning and can I swearing?